# Query funciona no phpmyadmin, mas nao funciona no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando fazer uma query via php no Mysql , mas não esta funcionando no PHP, mas funciona no PHPMYADMIN.

```
$check_in = strtotime($arrival);
$check_out = strtotime($departure);
```

Queries que já tentei no PHP...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = 5993 AND check_in > '$check_in' and check_in < '$check_out'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = '5993' AND check_in > '$check_in' and check_in < '$check_out'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = '5993' AND check_in > '" . $check_in . "' and check_in < '" . $check_out . "'
```

;

Full code:
         $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = '$post_id' AND check_in > '" . $check_in . "' and check_in < '" . $check_out . "'";
       echo nl2br($query);
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
        echo "achou";
        exit;
      } else {
        echo "nao achou nada";
        exit;
      }

Novo codigo, estou utilizando PDO. 
Desculpe a formatação, não consigo formatar para codigo.

$check_in = '1514764800';
        $check_out = '1525132800';

```
    $post_id = "5993";
     $query = ("SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND check_in > '$check_in' AND check_in < '$check_out'");
  // $query = ("SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = '$post_id' AND check_in > '" . 1514764800  . "' and check_in < '" . 1525132800  . "'");
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
    echo "achou";
    exit;
  } else {
    echo "nao achou nada";
    exit;
  }
```

[image: table]

Comment: A primeira versão está correta. Explica melhor o que é o "não funciona no php".

Comment: Faça um `echo nl2br($query)` pra ver os retornos

Comment: retorno do echo nl2br($query)  = SELECT * FROM wp_st_availability WHERE post_id = '5993' AND check_in > '1514764800' and check_in < '1525132800'

Comment: @bfavaretto ele executa ok no phpmyadmin ( retorna os resultados ) e no php não retorna nada no rowCount

Comment: Qual é o formato de $arrival e $departure? O strtotime está funcionando? Se estiver, faça `date('Y-m-d, $strtotime(...))`.

Comment: O strtotime ta funcionando sim.. $check_in vem 1514764800 e $check_out 1525132800

Comment: O problema não é o formato, pois quando eu pesquiso no phpmyadmin aparece os valores. Eu tirei as variaveis e coloquei o valor de check_in e check_out e não retornou nada no php. Fiz a mesma coisa no phpmyadmin e retornou os resultados

Comment: Pode estar dando erro na conexão ou na própria query. Não sei o que você usa para acessar o mysql (mysqli? pdo?), mas precisa chamar a função que te informa os erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, fiz assim:

No banco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código php:

```
 <?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

$id_post = 1;

$check_in = strtotime('2018-02-12') ;
$check_out = strtotime('2018-02-15');

//$check_in =1518393600;
//$check_out = 1518652800;

if($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE id='$id_post' AND 
check_in > '$check_in' AND check_in < '$check_out'")){
    while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row['nome'];
    }
}
```

resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que no banco o valor check_in é 1518393700, o valor da variável $check_in é menor que ele e o check_in é menor que o $check_out, ou seja, entre as duas, reveja na sua tabela os valores de check_in, talvez seja esse o problema, pra ter certeza da dos valores pesquisados, você pode fazer um var_dump($variavel); pra ver se variável está indo correta